# SQL server: Can concurrent threads update same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc that has this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) Batch_tbl
SET locked = 1
OUTPUT inserted.batchId INTO #batchId
FROM Batch_tbl 
WHERE locked = 0;
```

It updates the first row where locked = 0, and sets locked = 1.

If I have multiple threads, could there be a chance 2+ threads update the same row? This is assuming locked is never set back to 0 once it's 1.

If so, how can I make it such that 2+ threads always update distinct rows?

Comment: Any reason you're implementing your own lock table/engine instead of using MSSQL's built-in transaction rowlock? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Why would you think two threads could update the same row?  If so I don't believe MS would have ever been able to sell their product.

Comment: @Hogan I don't know what to think, hence the question.

Comment: @Hogan Yep, I'm very stupid for asking this. Happy?

Comment: Ok point taken, I did not mean to be nasty -- it seems clear to me that update locks are a fundamental part of relational DB functionality but maybe it is not so obvious.

Comment: @Hogan Actually, there's auto-commit and transactional modes for SQLServer.  However, even for auto-commit this is one single statement so it would be atomic.  (only operate in one connection at a time, others would block till first finished)  Till you learn them, Transactions are not obvious.  http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Comment: More info on the update lock type [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2009/11/13/update-locks.aspx) that was invented just to prevent deadlocks in situations like this.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Isn't that the same thing that I linked to MSDN for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**. When SQL Server wants to update a row, an `UPDATE` lock is acquired. This is compatible with other locks, like a shared lock (to read), but it's **NOT** compatible with another update lock.

So if two concurrent users attempt to update the same row, one of them will "win" and get the `UPDATE` Lock, while the other user / transaction will have to wait until the first update is done.

Comment: Sure, the second guy will have to wait to get the UPDATE lock - but whoever acquires the UPDATE lock last will ultimately set the row's data, overwriting previous values, correct?

Comment: @KyleM: if there is no checking for e.g. a `ROWVERSION` column or other column values - yes - the last process updating the data "wins"

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am I correct in stating that it is the job of the developer/ORM tools (e.g. Hibernate), and not the DBMS, to implement these protections such as optimistic versioning? Or do databases natively provide this type of protection? Thanks, and I hope this is not too off topic for this response.

Comment: Depends on which ORM you're using. EF uses a "compare all column values" approach by default, e.g. it uses the "old" column values that were stored at the time the data was read in the `UPDATE` statement, and if the row has changed in the mean time, nothing will be updated. But yes - it's the developer's job to ensure these kind of safe guards