# SQL Server - Strategy for Long-Running Aggregate Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, caching

## Scenario:

- ASP.Net 4.5 Web app that captures user "votes" for a video.
- After each vote, SQL Server 2012 stored proc calculates SUM of votes for the video.

## Problem:

- Small number of votes is fine performance-wise.
- When votes reach 100,000+, query can take 10+ seconds to finish (unacceptable time to wait).

## Questions:

1. Is a SQL Server job that runs every 15-30 minutes the way to go?
2. Can the SUM result be "cached" in a table column for the web app to use?
3. Any issues with job updating cached SUM while web app is accessing the same value?

Comment: Is that SPROC doing something besides SUM? SUM shouldn't take long at all.

Comment: Just SUM (It was a bit of an exaggeration on the actual time). There will be a point where processing time is too long to wait (probably more like in the millions), so some sort of caching will be needed.

Also, I don't want each vote to trigger the same query concurrently, as this will definitely hinder performance.

Comment: Instead of aggregating every time, can the stored proc calculate SUM = current SUM +/- 1?

Comment: Will there be concurrency issues if calculated that way? Say, 3 votes come in at the same time?

Comment: If the sums are stored in their own table, then no.  Executing the procedure 3 times would result in 3 updates.

Comment: Yes, they are. There is a RATING table with VID_ID foreign key to VIDEO table.

Comment: I still have concerns about concurrency, especially after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410009/sql-server-can-concurrent-threads-update-same-row

There will be times when multiple votes happen "simultaneously". How will SQL Server handle these?

Comment: Example: Total Votes = 1,000,000.

User A: Vote = +1
User B: Vote = +1

Both happen at exactly the same time.

Comment: From a SQL standpoint, no two transactions happen at exactly the same time.  Each call of a stored procedure is executed independently, regardless of timing.  Your case is different than the one the question you referenced -- you have no need to lock rows in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the SUM of 100k rows takes 10seconds means you have a bad table design. You're missing an index, or more. Updating a sum on 100k rows should take 10ms or less.

Aside from that, SQL Server can maintain the SUM for you. Simply create an indexed view on the desired expression. See [Create Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). `SUM` is a supported aggregate in indexed views.

Here is a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ba15/2).

A indexed view is superior to a homemade solution (eg. a column maintained in triggers) because, first of all, is *correct* and simpler (less code), is maintained by the engine in *any* situation and does not drift (eg. if a trigger is temporarily disabled). This is w/o even considering all the disadvantages inherent in *any* trigger based solution.

Comment: Thanks - it doesn't actually take that long. I was just projecting down the line with millions of rows, the query may be too slow for the user to wait. 

Do you see any issues with using a column in the VIDEO table, and having a stored proc concurrently increment/decrement on the fly (see comments on the original post)?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. I would say no. A sum on a table of that size should not be a problem, you may have a problem somewhere else. Once you get over a million rows you may want to consider this as an option but you will need to do a few other things also to ensure that the data does not become too stale too quickly.
2. The execution plan may be, but the result will not.
3. Yes, but you shouldn't notice it. When you perform the full table SELECT you will be locking the table so that the aggregate function can run, but this will only prevent writes. If you are taking an age to write a row and the aggregate function cannot lock the table you may get a problem but I cannot imagine how an application of this type would cause a noticeable lock.

Have you tried indexing this column so that the server generates column statistics? The SUM value (in my mind) would likely be a statistic so this may speed things up.