# Is it dangerous when plenty of users need one and the same table (simultaneous access for a table) in a Database?

Tags: sql-server, database-concurrency

I use the code of a server which serves each user by putting some personal data into a DB table. There are plenty of users and two of them for instance would like to put some data in the table in a DB. How will sql server perform in this case? Are there any mechanisms that are ready for such users' behavior (simultaneous access to a table)?
The functionality of the server is written with C# and uses SqlConnection.ConnectionString for each attempt of access.

Comment: This is fundamental to any good database.

Comment: It is not dangerous to update same database rows at the same time (I assume that is what you are asking). Databases like SQL Server make sure only single change is made to a row at a time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410009/sql-server-can-concurrent-threads-update-same-row.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean)